# Accesing elements list and print them out in HTML

Tags: python, html, arrays, video, element

Sorry if this is obvious, I'm new to python. I'm accesing mySql, appending all elements to a  list and the post to an html page. All works well until I need to grab the items on the list and print them put. Is not that I get an error (well, I'm getting many really :)), I just don't think I get how to do it. This is the piece of html code.

```
    {% for row in mylist %}
            {% print(mylist[1]) %}
            <h2{{ title }}/h2>
              <video width="520" controls>
                        <source src={{ link }} type="video/mp4">
                </video>
                <p>{{ description }}</p>
          <li>{{ message }}</li>
 {% endfor %}
 </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

In this way I can see the list being print out. This is the output

{'id': 2, 'title': 'Nice in mars', 'description': 'Do you want to know if there is someone in mars?', 'link': 'http::/something.com', 'sent': 0}

What I would like to accomplish is to go trought the entire list and grab title, description and link to create a dynamic html to list all the videos with the titles and descriptions (lets say like youtube)

Can anyone please help me understanding how to grab those values from the list and pass those to html?
Any help is really appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to render values to an HTML using jinja template. You can access the value like a dictionary. Ex: to get title use `row.title`

**Ex:**

```
{% for row in mylist %}
    <h2{{ row.title }}/h2>
      <video width="520" controls>
                <source src={{ row.link }} type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <p>{{ row.description }}</p>
  <li>{{ message }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```